# xarray selecting based on coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I have a bunch of data that I am inserting into an `xarray` Dataset. Below the dataset only has a single DataArray, but this might be more in future. Some of the dataset dimensions are annotated and I have inserted those as coordinates along one or multiple axes into the dataset. Now I would like to get a dataset for which coordinate `annot1 = '1'`.

I have tried a bunch of different dictionaries with the `ds.sel()` methods, but this does not seem to be the solution. How would I index the below dataset in such a fashion that I only get the data for which `annot1 = '1'`?

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as 

coords = {
    'x':['a','b','c','d'], 
    'y':['A','B','C','D'], 
    'z':['d_000','d_001','d_010','d_011','d_100','d_101'],
    'annot1': ('z',['0','1','0','1','0','1']),
    'annot2': ('z',['0','0','1','1','0','0']),
    'annot3': ('z',['0','0','0','0','1','1']),
    'intens':(['x','y'], np.arange(4**2).reshape((4,4))),
}


ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={
        'data': (['x','y','z'], np.random.randn(4,4,6))
    },
    coords=coords,
)
ds.sel(annot1 = '1') # How do i select only the data where annot1 is '1'?
```

Answer (score 3):

Found what I was looking for: `ds.sel(z=ds['annot1']=='1')`